# Using lightdm webkit greeter in 14.04

Tags: 14.04, lightdm, webkit

All guides indicate I need to change a setting in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf`, and that's how I did it last time, but there seems to have been some changes since that was written. `lightdm.conf` doesn't exist anymore.

**After installing the package, how can you replace the gtk-greeter with the webkit-greeter in 14.04?**

Comment: then try to create `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf` , I am sure lightdm will pick up that config file

Answer (score 1):

Create (for example) a file located in `/etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/` named `10-webkit.conf` with these lines:

```
[Seat:*]
greeter-session=lightdm-webkit-greeter
```